# Open file in iframe using button

Tags: javascript, html, button, iframe, onclick

So I have a javascript file that works and is triggered by an html button. The problem is, I am trying to make it so that, when the button is clicked, the game will appear inside an iframe window. How can this be achieved?

HTML:

```
<input id="clickThis" type="button" value="JavaScript Game" onclick="this.disabled='disabled'; target="jsgame"; thatFunction();" />     
<iframe name="jsgame" id="jsgame" width="700px" height="700px"> </iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem in your html code (related to `'` and `"` ) , change you button code to this :

```
<input id="clickThis" type="button" value="JavaScript Game" onclick="this.disabled='disabled'; target='jsgame'; thatFunction();" />
```

Than define the javascript function `thatFunction` that loads your page inside the iframe like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function thatFunction()
    {
        document.getElementById("jsgame").setAttribute("src","frame.php");
    }
</script>
```

or this code , because I noticed you're assigning the id of the iframe to the javascript variable `target`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function thatFunction()
    {
        document.getElementById(target).setAttribute("src","frame.php");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's really a simple javascript function

```
function openGame(){
    document.getElementById("jsgame").src="http://www.example.com"; 
}
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4xBzy/)